# Twilio Conversations API - unable to fetch record

Tags: python-3.x, twilio, twilio-conversations

I am trying to fetch a conversation following Twilio documentation verbatim [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/conversation-resource?code-sample=code-fetch-conversation&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=6.x#).

```
import os
from twilio.rest import Client


# Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
# and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

conversation = client.conversations \
                     .conversations('CHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') \
                     .fetch()
```

This returns a :

```
HTTP 404 error: Unable to fetch record: The requested resource /Conversations/CHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX was not found
```

However if I supply the conversation service id like so:

```
import os
from twilio.rest import Client


# Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
# and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

conversation = client.conversations \
                     .services("ISXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
                     .conversations('CHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') \
                     .fetch()
```

I get the conversation object correctly.  In my case I am using webhooks to catch when a participant joins a conversation, since the event doesn't return the service sid, only the conversation sid, it complicates what I am trying to do.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The short form conversations API, like this:

```py
conversation = client.conversations \
                     .conversations('CHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') \
                     .fetch()
```

only works if you are [using the default service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/conversation-resource#using-the-shortened-base-url). Otherwise you do need to provide the service SID.

If I were you I would store the conversations service SID as a config parameter in your application, perhaps set as an environment variable, so that you can refer to it when making requests to the API like this.

Comment: Gotcha - I wish the webhook events would contain not just the conversation sid but the conversation service sid.  My app is making using of dozens of different conversation services, and I was hoping I wouldn't have to create my own lookup table.

Comment: There is a case internally to add this parameter to the webhooks, so hopefully you can do away with the lookup table at some point.